# convert series of strings to datetimeobjects to extract month and year

Tags: python, pandas

Using python 3 for ML, one problem I have come across today is this. I have a pandas dataframe with one column containing dates.

```
data['Allfast time'].head()
0    31-Dec-14 17:55:00
1    31-Dec-14 22:55:00
2    31-Dec-14 09:30:00
3    01-Jan-15 10:55:00
4    01-Jan-15 21:15:00
Name: Allfast time, dtype: object
```

The to_datetime() command gives the following error:

```
TypeError: object of type 'datetime.time' has no len()
```

How do I create a new column data['month'] that contains the month only, extracted from data['Allfast time']?

Thank you!

Comment: Are these strings here? If so then `data['month'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Allfast time']).dt.month` will work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message implies that your Series contains not only strings but also at
least one `datetime.time` object. For example, the error message can be reproduced this way:

```
In [35]: test = pd.Series(['31-Dec-14 17:55:00', DT.time(21,15,00),])
In [36]: pd.to_datetime(test)
TypeError: object of type 'datetime.time' has no len()
```

Therefore, to convert this motley group of objects to Pandas Timestamps, pass `errors='coerce'` to `pd.to_datetime`. Invalid date strings and `datetime.time` objects will be replaced by `NaT` ([Not-a-Time](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/neps/datetime-proposal.html#datetime64)) objects:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as DT
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Allfast time': 
     ['31-Dec-14 17:55:00', '31-Dec-14 22:55:00', '31-Dec-14 09:30:00',
      '01-Jan-15 10:55:00', '01-Jan-15 21:15:00', 
      DT.time(21,15,00), DT.date(2000,1,1), DT.datetime(2000,1,1,8,10,20)]})

df['Allfast time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Allfast time'], errors='coerce')
print(df['Allfast time'].dt.month)
```

yields

```
0    12.0
1    12.0
2    12.0
3     1.0
4     1.0
5     NaN
6     1.0
7     1.0
Name: Allfast time, dtype: float64
```

Since a `datetime.time` has no month, the best you can do is assign NaN to represent the missing month.

Comment: Yes, this was indeed the case! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) for converting to datetime column `Allfast time` and then use [`dt.month`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.month.html) and [`dt.year`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.year.html):

```
print (df)
         Allfast time
0  31-Dec-14 17:55:00
1  31-Dec-14 22:55:00
2  31-Dec-14 09:30:00
3  01-Jan-15 10:55:00
4  01-Jan-15 21:15:00

print (df.dtypes)
Allfast time    object
dtype: object

df['Allfast time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Allfast time'])
df['months'] = df['Allfast time'].dt.month
df['year'] = df['Allfast time'].dt.year
print (df)
         Allfast time  months  year
0 2014-12-31 17:55:00      12  2014
1 2014-12-31 22:55:00      12  2014
2 2014-12-31 09:30:00      12  2014
3 2015-01-01 10:55:00       1  2015
4 2015-01-01 21:15:00       1  2015

print (df.dtypes)
Allfast time    datetime64[ns]
months                   int64
year                     int64
dtype: object
```